# Window.scroll only working once (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a simple React component to remember where you are on the page and place you there when returning.

Here's the code:

```
function ScrollCache() {
  window.scroll(0, parseInt(localStorage['scroll']));
  document.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    if (window.scrollY != 0) {
      localStorage['scroll'] = window.scrollY.toString();
    }
  })
  return (<></>)
}
```

Basically, it caches the last known scroll position, and uses `window.scroll(x, y)` to scroll to that position. I have verified that localStorage is working as intended with a `console.log` immediately before the `window.scroll`. I've also just tried a static `100` for the y coordinate. No matter what, it only scrolls once at reload and then never again when I'm navigating around.

I'm using React Router to go between web pages. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you don't change your localstorage somewhere else in your code? Do you call ScrollCache properly? Because I reproduced the code that you posted [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/save-scroll-o2g58?file=/src/App.js:400-401) and it works fine.

Comment: why are you add scroll event listener every time you want to cache the scroll?

Comment: Im pretty new to React.js so I'm just toying around :p I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: @GabrielNuñezdeAndrade I have no idea how useEffect works, and I'm reading up on it now, but that was indeed the issue. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the scroll event listener every time you want to cache the scroll.

Instead, try this:

```
const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, {
        passive: true
    });
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
}, [scrollPosition]);

useEffect(() => {
   localStorage['scroll'] = scrollPosition.toString();
}, [scrollPosition);

const handleScroll = () => {
    const position = window.pageYOffset;
    setScrollPosition(position);
};
```

Comment: It would improve the performance if you debounce the localStorage writes